# client_max_body_size 2M; is not working with nginx version: nginx/1.6.3 on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Hi am working on server setup of my rails app and my 
`client_max_body_size 2M;` is not working with `nginx version: nginx/1.6.3` on ubuntu 14.04. Please help me out I got stucked with this issue.

Comment: me too having same doubt not getting it

Comment: What is the error ? Is it getting ignored ? Have you tried to set it to 0 ?

Comment: yes I had tried that also but its not working. Ihad cleared my cookies cache reload and restart nginx server. Tried giving this line inside server and outside  in ninginx.conf file but its not at all working

Answer (score 0):

You should reload nginx config or restart it to apply your changes. Seems like you don't do it.

Sometimes possible cases when init.d script for nginx has a problem and it doesn't restart or reload nginx correctly. In this case stop nginx, then check use `ps aux` that nginx is stopped (otherwise kill it) and start nginx again (don't forget to investigate problem with init.d script and fix it after).

Comment: I had reloaded and restart the nginx server but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

try, also with sendfile and send_timeout!

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
sendfile on;
send_timeout 1800;
```